# why loadrunner don't work in weblogic,and no any error

Tags: loadrunner

Loadrunner scripts can run in tomcat,donnot work in weblogic,and Background monitoring everything was normal,i donnot konw it is why ? please .

Answer (score 0):

Define "do not work in Weblogic" and what type of script....     LoadRunner has a strong history of working in environments where Weblogic is present from an execution and a monitoring perspective.

Comment: in tomcat,Script can execute all method completly to the background,But under the weblogic method also can perform complete ,finally it is not to commit the transaction ,lead to Data cannot be written.

Comment: What type of script/client?  HTTP?   Java?  What variant of Java?   JMX for Monitoring?  SNMP for Monitoring?   Custom running on the server to interface?   Representing remote client?

Comment: Thanks for your help! problem has been resolved! Sincerely thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry,the problem is that I help a friend,I don't konw how he resolved,after i asked ,share to you!